# Route not found in lazy loaded sub module

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading

Ok I have a strange situation here. Maybe I am pushing nesting too far but let's see.

I have a stack of modules that look like: 
AppModule -> QuoteModule -> CarModule

AppModule and QuoteModule are loaded, CarModule is lazy loaded.

Now in the AppModule Routing, I have this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { QuoteComponent } from '@modules/quote/components/quote/quote.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'quote', component: QuoteComponent },
    { path: 'maintenance', loadChildren: 'app/modules/maintenance/maintenance.module#MaintenanceModule' },
    { path: 'error', loadChildren: 'app/modules/errors/errors.module#ErrorsModule' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This route is fine. QuoteComponent loads when hitting /quote

In my quote module, I have this routing:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { QuoteComponent } from '@modules/quote/components/quote/quote.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: QuoteComponent, children: [
        { path: 'quote/car', loadChildren: 'app/modules/quote/car/car.module#CarModule'}
    ]},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class QuoteRoutingModule { }
```

This works fine, when hitting /quote/car, I am lazy loading the car module and hit the blank route of the CarModule routing, which is:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CarInfoComponent } from '@modules/quote/car/components/car-info/car-info.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', children: [
        { path: 'quote/car/info', component: CarInfoComponent, outlet: 'quote'}
    ]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CarRoutingModule { }
```

My problem is that my car module will be separate in sub route like: quote/car/info, quote/car/color, quote/car/something...

When I hit quote/car/info, I get this error: `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'quote/car/info'`

**edit:** 
My CarModule looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { CarRoutingModule } from './car-routing.module';
import { CarInfoComponent } from './components/car-info/car-info.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        CarRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [CarInfoComponent],
    exports: [CarInfoComponent]
})
export class CarModule { }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: with `quote/car/car/info` you should get it.  if you still want quote/car/info change the path `car/info` to `info` in the routing of the CarModule

Comment: is it car/info or /info in car module ? beacuse when car module is loaded, it is quote/car...then for info, path should be info only...try once

Comment: { path: 'info', component: CarInfoComponent, outlet: 'quote'}

Comment: unfortunalty not. Its not working. Its like, if in my QuoteComponent the route quote/car/info is not defined, it's not accessing the carModule

Comment: In CarModule routing, I tried with quote/car/info, car/info and just info. it's not working

Comment: How looks your carModule? and route in carModule?

Comment: This is it: const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: CarInfoComponent, outlet: 'quote', children: [
        { path: 'car/info', component: CarInfoComponent, outlet: 'quote'}
    ]}
];

Comment: could you add CarModule in the post?

Comment: I edited my post with the CarModule

Comment: Thanks and CarRoutingModule? Now I see you should import RouterModule

Comment: I updated all Routing modules

Comment: @Fetrarij not sure to understand what you mean, I should import RouterModule?

Comment: you already have it in CarRoutingModule. I dont see anything wrong unless you should use:  { path: 'info', component: CarInfoComponent}..and remove the outlet.. this should work

Answer (score 0):

Got it. For reference, here is how I solved it:

In my AppComponent, I had a `<router-outlet>` to load the QuoteComponent, and inside the `QuoteComponent`, I had a `<router-outlet name="quote">` in which I was trying to load childrens routes of `CarComponent`.

I just removed the `name="quote"` from the QuoteComponent's router-outlet and all reference to the quote outlet in children's route and it worked.

I tough that I had to identify the sub outlet, but apparently there is a bubble up effect in outlets. Children's routes will be loaded in the first parent outlet of the hierarchy.

I hope it helps someone.